# Does react-router-v4 supports dynamic routing?

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I tried to add routes dynamically by using v3 but it didn't support it. React-router-v4 supports dynamic routing or not?

Comment: Did you find the way to do it. If so, Please let us know how did you do .Thanks in advance

Comment: Nope I did not find it yet :(

Answer (score 0):

It's quite unclear to me what you actually mean by dynamic routing? Are you thinking of routes provided by the API, or any sort other external source?

Sure you can, but you got to think your structure through. The easiest way to achieve that is to map them inside of your `Switch` Component:

```
<Switch>
  { routesList.map((route) => (
      <Route
        key={route._id}
        path={route.path}
        component={route.component}
        {...route.props} // some custom props, maybe?
      />
    )
  )}

 <Route path='/' component={HomePage} />
 <Route path='/about' component={About} />
</Switch>
```