# Reactjs : Why does Children.count(children) is always 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, slider, components

I have to build a custom slider in reactjs wherein the count of child component is always 0.I'm fetching the images from the API and passing them from the parent component to the child component.When I pass the images statically the slider works fine and count of the children is exactly the same as the number of images.Here is my code

MainBanner Component

```
import React from "react";
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import SlideShow from './SlideShow';
import {getBannerImages} from '../actions/landingPageActions';
import {getMainBannerImages} from '../selectors';

class MainBanner extends React.Component{

  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.getBannerImages();
  }

  render(){
    const {bannerImages} = this.props
    return(
      <div className="row">
          <SlideShow>
          {bannerImages && bannerImages.map((image,i)=>
            <img key={i} src={`${image.mainbannerimages}`} alt="main banner" width="100%" height="350px" />
          )}
          </SlideShow>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
  return {
    bannerImages:getMainBannerImages(state)
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{getBannerImages})(MainBanner);
```

Child Component (Slider)

```
import React, { Component, Children } from 'react';
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';

class SlideShow extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.leftSlide=this.leftSlide.bind(this);
    this.showNext=this.showNext.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      total: 0,
      current: 0,
    }
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    const { children } = this.props;
      console.log(Children.count(children));
    this.setState({ total: Children.count(children) });
    this.interval = setInterval(this.showNext, 5000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  showNext = () => {
    const { total, current } = this.state;
    console.log(total);
    this.setState({
      current: current + 1 === total? 0 : current + 1
    });
  };

  leftSlide=()=>{
    const { total, current } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      current: current - 1 <= 0 ? 0 : current - 1
    });
    console.log(this.state.current);
  }

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;
    const bullets = Array(this.state.total).fill("○");
    bullets[this.state.current] = "●";
    return (
      <div className="slideshow">
        <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
          className="group"
          transitionName="bannerSlideTransistion"
          transitionEnterTimeout={800}
          transitionLeaveTimeout={800}>
          {Children.toArray(children)[this.state.current]}
        </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
        <div className="mainBannerNavigators">
          <span className="leftArrow" onClick={this.leftSlide}><i className="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
          <span className="rightArrow" onClick={this.showNext}><i className="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default SlideShow;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what version of React are you using?

Comment: @patryk React 15.i guess it is not the problem with the react version because when I add 4 images instead of getting the images from api., the total count of the children is 4. And the slider works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering the question

> Why does Children.count(children) is always 0

Because it's supposed to return 0.

This is caused due to component's lifecycle. You mount the `SlideShow` component on render, before even having the data fetched from the API. You try to pass along with it, some images, although because you don't have them fetched yet, they simply aren't rendered. Meaning, at the moment of `SlideShow` mount, it has no `children` at all.

When you receive a response back from the server, your `SlideShow` component is being `updated`, with provided, mapped images.

If you wanna catch the moment of the update, I recommend you using `componentWillReceiveProps` function. Which takes an argument, new props object.
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops

```
componentWillReciveProps(newProps) {
  this.setState((state) => ({
    total: Children.count(newProps.children) 
  }))
}
```

Although, I'm not completely convinced whether you actually would need the value, to be stored in your component's state. I'd recommend you to get the count value at the `showNext`. That way, it would always be up to date, and I don't really see any benefit from storing it locally.

Comment: Thanks @patryk.As you recommended, I got the count value in showNext.It's working fine now.Can I make API request in componentWillReceiveProps on route change?

Comment: could u please answer for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44872941/does-react-router-v4-supports-dynamic-routing?noredirect=1#comment84076210_44872941